# How to generate an accurate frequency in android

Tags: android, audio, frequency

For generating the desired frequencies by number in android i know 2 ways and each has it's own big problems.

first way is PCM_16_bit:

```
    frequency = (int) frequency;
    final int numberOfSamples = duration * sampleRate;
    final byte[] generatedSnd = new byte[numberOfSamples * 2];
    double dVal;

    int idx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSamples; ++i) {
        dVal = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (sampleRate / frequency));

        // convert to 16 bit pcm sound array
        // assumes the sample buffer is normalised.

        // scale to maximum amplitude
        short val = (short) ((dVal * 32767));

        // in 16 bit wav PCM, first byte is the low order byte
        generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
        generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);

       }

    audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                   sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                   AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, generatedSnd.length,
                   AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);

    audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        loudnessEnhancer = new LoudnessEnhancer(audioTrack.getAudioSessionId());

        loudnessEnhancer.setTargetGain(maxFrequency - (int) frequency);

    }
```

Which is only for short values so no precision number and limited amplitude so requires LoudnessEnhancer with dependency of android 4.4 which adds gain and reduces the quality.

The second way is:

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                final int numberOfSamples = duration * sampleRate * 4;
                final float[] generatedSnd = new float[numberOfSamples];

                float amplitude = 2;//Increase in amplitude has a relation with increase in noise.  

                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSamples; ++i)
                    generatedSnd[i] = (float) (Math.sin((2 * Math.PI * i * frequency) / sampleRate)) * amplitude;

                audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT, generatedSnd.length,
                        AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);

                audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length, AudioTrack.WRITE_BLOCKING);
```

Which only adds one precision but solves the amplitude problem for me but it requires android 5 which is inefficient and also 1 precision is not enough for very low notes like second piano octave.

Is making more precise frequencies possible?
Is There Another Way?

Comment: What is the value of `frequency` here?

Answer (score 0):

try  this I think its OK:

```
  isPlaying = true;
  int sampleRate = 44100;// 44.1 KHz
  double dnumSamples = (double) duration * sampleRate;
  dnumSamples = Math.ceil(dnumSamples);
  int numSamples = (int) dnumSamples;
  double[] sample = new double[numSamples];
  byte[] generatedSnd = new byte[2 * numSamples];
  for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {      // Fill the sample array
    sample[i] = Math.sin(freq * 2 * Math.PI * i / (sampleRate));
  }

  // convert to 16 bit pcm sound array
  // assumes the sample buffer is normalized.
  // convert to 16 bit pcm sound array
  // assumes the sample buffer is normalised.
  int idx = 0;
  int i;

  int ramp = numSamples / 20;  // Amplitude ramp as a percent of sample count

  for (i = 0; i < ramp; ++i) {  // Ramp amplitude up (to avoid clicks)
    // Ramp up to maximum
    final short val = (short) (sample[i] * 32767 * i / ramp);
    // in 16 bit wav PCM, first byte is the low order byte
    generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
    generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);
  }

  for (i = ramp; i < numSamples - ramp;
       ++i) {                        // Max amplitude for most of the samples
    // scale to maximum amplitude
    final short val = (short) (sample[i] * 32767);
    // in 16 bit wav PCM, first byte is the low order byte
    generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
    generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);
  }

  for (i = numSamples - ramp; i < numSamples; ++i) { // Ramp amplitude down
    // Ramp down to zero
    final short val = (short) (sample[i] * 32767 * (numSamples - i) / ramp);
    // in 16 bit wav PCM, first byte is the low order byte
    generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
    generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);
  }

  try {
    int bufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    audioTrack =
            new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

    audioTrack.setNotificationMarkerPosition(numSamples);
    audioTrack.setPlaybackPositionUpdateListener(
            new AudioTrack.OnPlaybackPositionUpdateListener() {
              @Override public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioTrack track) {
                // nothing to do
              }

              @Override public void onMarkerReached(AudioTrack track) {
               // toneStoppedListener.onToneStopped();
              }
            });

    // Sanity Check for max volume, set after write method to handle issue in android
    // v 4.0.3
    float maxVolume = AudioTrack.getMaxVolume();

    if (volume > maxVolume) {
      volume = maxVolume;
    } else if (volume < 0) {
      volume = 0;
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
      audioTrack.setVolume(volume);
    } else {
      audioTrack.setStereoVolume(volume, volume);
    }

    audioTrack.play(); // Play the track
    audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);    // Load the track
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: Hi I want to set duration lower than 0.06 but my generated not working and don't have any voice .Do you know reason?